# Generate a E-mail (Outlook) from a Word document

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, ms-word

I'm trying to create a code that opens each word document in a specific folder, and extract from the file the .subject, .to and .body of the e-mail.

For instance, there is an example of the file format below. But the number of e-mails isnt fixed.. the subject always start with the same word, also the the body.

---

xxx@xxxx.xx xxx@xxxx.xx xxx@xxxx.xx xxx@xxxx.xx xxx@xxxx.xx

Subject Example - VBA Code - MM/DD/YYYY

Dear Collegues,

Etc, Etc, etc

I'`ve tried a several number of different codes, but none of them worked 100% properly. It is a daily routine that i have to send to the clients a settlement advice.

Code below isn't working properly.

```
Sub CreateEmailFromWord()

    ' Define Outlook application
    Dim outlookApp As Object
    Set outlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    ' Define email item
    Dim emailItem As Object
    Set emailItem = outlookApp.CreateItem(0) ' 0 represents an email

    ' Open the Word document
    Dim wdApp As Object
    Set wdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    
    ' Replace "C:\Path\To\Your\Document.docx" with the path to your Word document
    Dim wdDoc As Object
    Set wdDoc = wdApp.Documents.Open("C:\Path\To\Your\Document.docx")

    ' Find the recipient in the document body (assuming recipients are in email format)
    Dim recipient As String
    recipient = ExtractInformation(wdDoc.Content, "[\w\.-]+@[\w\.-]+")

    ' Find the subject in the document body
    Dim subject As String
    subject = ExtractInformation(wdDoc.Content, "Derivative Operation Settlement - (.+?)\r")

    ' Find the email body
    Dim emailBody As String
    emailBody = ExtractInformation(wdDoc.Content, "Dear Sirs,[\s\S]+")

    ' Fill in the email information
    emailItem.To = recipient
    emailItem.Subject = subject
    emailItem.Body = emailBody

    ' Display the email before sending (optional)
    emailItem.Display

    ' Send the email
    ' emailItem.Send

    ' Close the Word document
    wdDoc.Close False
    Set wdDoc = Nothing

    ' Quit the Word application
    wdApp.Quit
    Set wdApp = Nothing

    ' Clean up Outlook objects
    Set emailItem = Nothing
    Set outlookApp = Nothing

End Sub

Function ExtractInformation(text As String, pattern As String) As String
    Dim regex As Object
    Set regex = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    With regex
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = True
        .IgnoreCase = True
        .Pattern = pattern
    End With

    Dim match As Object
    Set match = regex.Execute(text)

    If match.Count > 0 Then
        ExtractInformation = match(0)
    Else
        ExtractInformation = ""
    End If
End Function
```

Updating the code so far:

```
  Sub CreateEmailsFromWordDocuments()

   Dim outlookApp As Object
   Set outlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

   ' Define o caminho da pasta
   Dim folderPath As String
   folderPath = "FolderPath"

   Dim fileName As String
   fileName = Dir(folderPath & "*.docx")

Do While fileName <> ""
Dim emailItem As Object
Set emailItem = outlookApp.CreateItem(0)

Dim wdApp As Object
Set wdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")

Dim wdDoc As Object
Set wdDoc = wdApp.Documents.Open(folderPath & fileName)
Dim recipient As String
recipient = ExtractInformation(wdDoc.Content, " 
([\w\.-]+@[\w\.-]+(;|$))+")


Dim subject As String
subject = ExtractInformation(wdDoc.Content.text, "Liquidação de 
Operação de Derivativo*(.+?)\r")

Dim emailBody As String
emailBody = ExtractInformation(wdDoc.Content.text, "Prezados 
Senhores,[\s\S]+")

With emailItem
.To = recipient
.subject = subject
.CC = "Liquidação"
.Body = emailBody
.Display
End With


wdDoc.Close False
Set wdDoc = Nothing


wdApp.Quit
Set wdApp = Nothing

fileName = Dir
Loop

' Limpa a referência ao aplicativo Outlook
 Set outlookApp = Nothing
 End Sub


 Function ExtractInformation(text As String, pattern As String) 
 As String

Dim regex As Object
Set regex = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
With regex
.Global = True
.MultiLine = True
.IgnoreCase = True
.pattern = pattern
 End With

Dim match As Object
Set match = regex.Execute(text)

If match.Count > 0 Then
ExtractInformation = match(0)
Else
ExtractInformation = ""
End If
End Function
```

Comment: "isn't working properly" - what exactly is your code doing or not doing and how is that different from what you want?

Comment: I need to keep the format from the word doc to the e-mail and the code isnt extracting all e-mails, just the first.

Comment: Would help a lot if you could share a dummy Word doc which mirrors the format of the ones you're working with.  Please be sure to replace any confidential info with placeholder text.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a pattern which might match multiple parts of your text (such as when looking for mails) you can do something like the example below: change your  `ExtractInformation` function to return a `Collection` of matches, and either loop over them all (as for emails) or just use the first item (subject etc)

```vb
Sub tester()
    Dim m, matches As Collection
    
    Set matches = ExtractInformation( _
         "Hello abc@xxxx.xx def@xxxx.xx ghi@xxxx.xx jkl@xxxx.xx mno@xxxx.xx world", _
         "[\w\.-]+@[\w\.-]+")
    
    For Each m In matches
        Debug.Print m
        'emailItem.Recipients.Add m
    Next m
End Sub


'Return a collection of all matches to pattern `pattern` in `text`
Function ExtractInformation(text As String, pattern As String) As Collection
    Dim matches As Object, match As Object
    
    With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = True
        .IgnoreCase = True
        .pattern = pattern
        Set matches = .Execute(text)
    End With
    
    Set ExtractInformation = New Collection
    For Each match In matches
        ExtractInformation.Add match.Value
    Next match
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

- `recipient` only extract the first email address from the doc.
- Change RegExp pattern to catch all email address and replace the space with `;`. Match `abc@abc.com jack@cde.net`

```vb
    recipient = Replace(ExtractInformation(wdDoc.Content, "([\w\.-]+@[\w\.-]+\s*)+"), " ", ";")
```

- Match `abc@abc.com;jack@cde.net`

```
recipient = ExtractInformation(wdDoc.Content, "([\w\.-]+@[\w\.-]+(;|$))+")
```

Comment: I didnt get exactly what you mean with "Change RegExp pattern to catch all email address". I saw that is extracting only the first e-mail but I still didnt get how to fix it. Im a beginner with VBA, sorry, hahah.

Comment: Replace `recipient = ExtractInformation(wdDoc.Content, "[\w\.-]+@[\w\.-]+")` with the code in my reply.

Comment: From -> recipient = ExtractInformation(wdDoc.Content, "[\w\.-]+@[\w\.-]+")
to -> recipient = Replace(ExtractInformation(wdDoc.Content, "([\w\.-]+@[\w\.-]+\s*)+"), " ", ",")

didnt work, stil extracting just the first one

Comment: What's email in your document? Is it seperated with a space?

Comment: The original seems to extract ONE single recipient (without loop). If to find all recipients (assumed are in email format) and then loop through recipients to add onto the email may work. Sth like,
```
Dim recipients As Collection
        Set recipients = ExtractInformation(wdDoc.Content.Text, "[\w\.-]+@[\w\.-]+")

        Dim recipient As Variant
        For Each recipient In recipients
            emailItem.Recipients.Add recipient
        Next recipient
```

Comment: They re separated with semicolon ";"

Comment: Ill try this Loop

Comment: That's the problem. It is a space instead of `;` in your post. You don't need loop. Try `recipient = ExtractInformation(wdDoc.Content, "([\w\.-]+@[\w\.-]+(;|$))+")`

Comment: you're the man! It worked withou a loop!

Answer (score 0):

In combination of taller and Tim's comprehensive comments, re-drafted your original VB as below, hope it helps a bit.

- Loop through all Word docs within a folder.
- Improved Recipient handling, to loop through all recipients.
- Improved object handling.
- Added "alert - display emails" before sending (currently set as MANUALLY SEND), i.e. 1 purpose to check each loop runs.
- Adoptted of 'ExtractInformation', creates a regular expression object with specified pattern and options.

```
Sub CreateEmailsFromWordDocuments()
    Dim outlookApp As Object
    Set outlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    '// Set the folder path
    Dim folderPath As String
    folderPath = "C:\Path\To\Your\Folder\"

    Dim fileName As String
    fileName = Dir(folderPath & "*.docx")

    Do While fileName <> ""
        Dim emailItem As Object
        Set emailItem = outlookApp.CreateItem(0)

        Dim wdApp As Object
        Set wdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")

        Dim wdDoc As Object
        Set wdDoc = wdApp.Documents.Open(folderPath & fileName)

        Dim recipients As Collection
        Set recipients = ExtractInformation(wdDoc.Content.Text, "[\w\.-]+@[\w\.-]+")

        Dim recipient As Variant
        For Each recipient In recipients
            emailItem.Recipients.Add recipient
        Next recipient

        Dim subject As String
        subject = ExtractInformation(wdDoc.Content.Text, "Derivative Operation Settlement - (.+?)\r")

        Dim emailBody As String
        emailBody = ExtractInformation(wdDoc.Content.Text, "Dear Sirs,[\s\S]+")

        emailItem.Subject = subject
        emailItem.Body = emailBody
        emailItem.Display

        '// Send the email (uncommetn to send auto!)
        ' emailItem.Send

        wdDoc.Close False
        Set wdDoc = Nothing
        wdApp.Quit
        Set wdApp = Nothing
        fileName = Dir
    Loop

    '// Cleanup cache
    Set outlookApp = Nothing
End Sub

Function ExtractInformation(text As String, pattern As String) As Collection
    Dim matches As Object, match As Object

    With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = True
        .IgnoreCase = True
        .pattern = pattern
        Set matches = .Execute(text)
    End With

    Set ExtractInformation = New Collection
    For Each match In matches
        ExtractInformation.Add match.Value
    Next match
End Function
```